# PHP Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 6 Getting error

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I converted my query to an array.

```
$filterQuery = DB::table('view_vi_properties');
$filterQuery->select('id','name','bedrooms','max_guests','min_stay','private_pool','private_pool_text','price','security_deposit','pets_allowed','latitude','longitude','pro_address1','pro_address2','pro_city','country','primary_image','slug','rooms');
$filterQuery->whereNotIn('id', explode(',', $comma_property_id));
$filterQuery->whereNotIn('rooms_id', explode(',', $comma_room_id));
$filterQuery->whereNotIn('block_name', explode(',', $comma_block_name));
$filterQuery->where('status', 1)->groupBy('id');
$filterQuery->orderBy('name', 'asc');
$results = $filterQuery->get()->toArray();
print_r($results);
```

and I'm getting an array but the error is still showing

```
Array   (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Candolim
            [bedrooms] => 5
            [max_guests] => 9
            [min_stay] => 3
            [primary_image] => 1646566320.jpg
            [slug] => candolim
            [rooms] => 7 BR
        )
   )
```

Comment: When are you getting the error? What are you doing with `$results`?

Comment: i want to pass **$results** into view file

Answer (score 1):

`$filterQuery->get()` returns you a `Collection` of `StdClass` items, and `toArray()` converts only `Collection` object, but not items inside of it (not working recursively as you want).

The easiest way is to change `DB::table('view_vi_properties');` to corresponding Eloquent model, lets assume you model is `ViewViProperties`.In this case `$filterQuery->get()` will return a `Collection` of `ViewViProperties` class and `toArray()` will be able to convert all data to array recursivley.

If you don't want to use Eloquent then you need to convert each item separately or refer to them with object syntax like `$results[0]->id`.

Comment: if i use model **ViewViProperties** then how to use whereNotIn condations

Comment: ```whereNotIn``` works with Eloquent as well, just replace ```$filterQuery=DB::table('view_vi_properties')``` with  ```$filterQuery=ViewViProperties::query();```

Comment: @Hola you should also remove the `->groupBy('id')` from your query. aggregation on id is no aggregation if there is no joining of another tables.

Answer (score 0):

The issue mentioned above is correct because toArray() converted the parent objects to an array, but not child objects. To convert child objects to array also can be achieved through:

```
$result  = json_decode(json_encode($results), true);
```

Comment: It's not exactly true. when you run `toArray()` on a collection of models, it propagates to the model instances and they get converted to array too. The problem OP has is that he has a collection of objects and not models.